# how to give animation to this html code using css and js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

in this code i'm trying to put some animation for this candle.i'm not too familiar with the animation using js and css,that's why i'm posting this question.my doubt is how we can limit the  time for a particular event.in this code i want to move the flame left and right by a bit continuously up-to press the stop key.if i will give some css property it may work for some time,but i want to continue the animation until the second button is clicked.is it possible to do without loading any external library? if it ,how?

```js
function fire()
{
    document.getElementById("candle-flame").className="img-flame";
    document.getElementById("candle").className="img-candle";
}
function stop(){
        document.getElementById("candle-flame").className="img-flame before-click";
    document.getElementById("candle").className="img-candle before-click-candle"
}
```

```css
.candle-container{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    
}
.candle-flame{
    margin-left: 10%;
    
}
.candl{
    margin-left: 91%;
}
    .img-candle{
         /*position: absolute;*/
        height: 100%;
        width: 292%;
       /* z-index: 9;*/
        overflow: none;
    }
    .before-click-candle{
        margin-top: 185%;
    }
.img-flame{
    /*position: absolute;*/
    margin-left: 20%;
    /*z-index: 10;*/
    margin-left: 103.5%;
    margin-bottom: -4%;
    width: 4%;
    height: 33%;
   
}
.before-click{
    display: none;
     
}

/*.after-click{
    display: block;
}*/
.fire-box{
    float: left;
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: medium;
    width: 32%;
    height: 14%;
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-left: 27%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 22%;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="candle-container">
            <div  class="candle-flame  ">
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3fab.png" class="img-flame" id="candle-flame"  class="img-flame  before-click">
            </div>
            <div class="candl">
               <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDdGA.png" class="img-candle" id="candle" class="img-candle before-click-candle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fire-box">
            <button type="button" onclick="fire()">Fire</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="stop()">Stop Fire</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: I guess u will need this..http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: check this http://cssanimate.com/